# sbt play-java is not installing dependencies

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, dependencies, sbt

I started a Play 2 Java project from scratch. I'm using Apache's httpcomponent libraries and added them to build.sbt. When I run `sbt build` I get an error message saying "symbol not found" referring to the includes in the java files.

The imports which cause the problem are the following:

- org.apache.http.HttpResponse
- org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory
- org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts
- org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
- org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder

Other imports like oracle and gson work without a problem.

Examining Ivy's cache I found other versions than the ones are present. If I set the version number in build.sbt to the version in Ivy the imports still can't be found. I have deleted the ivy2 cache but it didn't help either.

I use Intellij 14, it can't find the dependencies either. It offers to add them to the classpath and succeeds in finding them thereafter. However sbt still can't find them.

**build.sbt:**

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://" + Path.userHome.absolutePath + "/.m2/repository"
name := """Bayeu2"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

val httpComponentClient = "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcomponents-client" % "4.5.+"

val httpComponentCore = "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcomponents-core" % "4.4.+"

val oracle = "com.oracle" % "oracle" % "12.1.0.1"

val gson = "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  jdbc,
  httpComponentClient,
  httpComponentCore,
  oracle,
  gson
)

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

**Update**

I think it's strange that only the *org.apache.http* imports fail. Therefore I imported a different library to test whether adding it would work. Sure enough it did. My current theory is that Play uses *org.apache.http* itself or an other implementation of the interface and the import fails because of a version conflict.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but shouldn't the revisions be like `"4.5.+"` instead of `"4.5.1+"`?

Comment: You are indeed right, I've checked the Manual. But even with the corrected version string the imports do not work :(